# Triggering "cellValueChanged" event in Angular AG Grid custom renderer component on select change

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Triggering "cellValueChanged" event in Angular AG Grid custom renderer component on select change
I'm using Angular AG Grid with a custom renderer component. I want to trigger the (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)" event when the user changes the value of a select element inside the component. However, I'm unable to get it working.

Here's what I've tried:

running api.refreshCells after updating data, data is updated but event isn't fired.
tried api.stopEditing/startEditing it isn't firing cellEditingStopped

I'm looking for a clean and efficient way to trigger the cellValueChanged event when the select element inside my custom renderer component changes.

Comment: please share some code, a stackblitz with the issue replicated and expected result!]